# JSON results keep return false

Tags: asp.net, json, vb.net

i am trying to send this JSON and it keep returns me false: Reason: NO TOKEN. Is there anything wrong with the JSON string?

**URL**

```
http://123.123.123.123/php/push/push.php
```

**JSON** (my third party ask me to put it in the body and in JSON format)

```
{
   "device":"Android",
   "message":"Testing",
   "Id":"15073116192095313120",
   "img":"",
   "token":[
      "DJISIODJOIS485uhhhifsejf9fdg"
   ]
}
```

**SEND REQUEST** (do I need the *?data=*)

```
http://123.123.123.123/php/push/push.php?data={"device":"Android","message":"Testing","Id":"15073116192095313120","img":"","token":["DJISIODJOIS485uhhhifsejf9fdg"]}
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
        Dim data As String

        data += "{""device"":""" + Device
        data += """,""" + "message"":""" + Message
        data += """,""" + "Id"":""" + ID

        If Device="Android" Then data += """,""" + "img"":""" + Img

        data += """,""" + "token"":[""" + token + """]"
        data += "}"

        Dim URL As String = Convert.ToString(http://123.123.123.123/php/push/push.php & "?") + data

        ' ## Perform an HTTP Get Request
        Dim response As String = PerformHTTPGet(URL)
```

Comment: Why is the token being passed an array of string values? Is that right?

Comment: yep, they gave me the format in []

Comment: It seems unlikely that a field named "token" would be an array. You need to talk to whoever owns this API, this isn't something StackOverflow users can help you with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't something StackOverflow users can help with.

Comment: You might need to encode the `data` portion of the URL; [vb.net has functions for this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

Comment: token is an array field.
token:[abc, cde,efg]

Comment: Or, as I see you say "my third party ask me to put it in the body and in JSON format", [here is a short routine](https://gist.github.com/six519/5ed917850f402b94ee6b) for POSTing JSON.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post JSON on URL HTTP Web Request with VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457191/post-json-on-url-http-web-request-with-vb-net)

Comment: yep already encoded the data and it works xD

Comment: I encoded with the below code

            Dim httpWReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(URL & "?"), HttpWebRequest)
            Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding()
            Dim postData As String
            postData += EncodedData
            Dim data As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)
            httpWReq.Method = "POST"
            httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json"
            httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length
            Using stream As Stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream()
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
            End Using