# Okta - Primary Authentication with Public Application using VB.Net

Tags: okta, okta-api

Using the API documentation, we are trying to use this for authenticating:
Primary Authentication with Public Application:

http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn.html#primary-authentication-with-public-application:
Authenticates a user with username/password credentials via a public application

Request Example

```html
curl -v -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "username": "dade.murphy@example.com",
  "password": "correcthorsebatterystaple",
  "relayState": "/myapp/some/deep/link/i/want/to/return/to",
  "options": {
    "multiOptionalFactorEnroll": false,
    "warnBeforePasswordExpired": false
  }
}'
```

Trying this in VB.Net, we get:

```html
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://dev-XXX.oktapreview.com/api/v1/authn")
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(.UserName, .Password)
request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.Method = "POST"

Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

When we get to the response, it gives an error of "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." and no more helpful info.

Obviously what we want to do is to do a WebRequest with the properly formatted parameters and return a WebResponse that we can interrogate for the Success Response:

```html
{
  "expiresAt": "2015-11-03T10:15:57.000Z",
  "status": "SUCCESS",
  "relayState": "/myapp/some/deep/link/i/want/to/return/to",
  "sessionToken": "00Fpzf4en68pCXTsMjcX8JPMctzN2Wiw4LDOBL_9pe",
  "_embedded": {
    "user": {
      "id": "00ub0oNGTSWTBKOLGLNR",
      "passwordChanged": "2015-09-08T20:14:45.000Z",
      "profile": {
        "login": "dade.murphy@example.com",
        "firstName": "Dade",
        "lastName": "Murphy",
        "locale": "en_US",
        "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting credentials on the request instead of sending the JSON payload.

Check out this example:
http://dotnetpad.com/7ri4979f

Based off [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457191/post-json-on-url-http-web-request-with-vb-net/28891563#28891563).

Comment: Thank you for your response, Thomas!